Add row split line between cells right on multirow cell
I would like to add horizontal split line between D,E,F,G cells. I have try add \hline at the end, but it will split the whole line. The multrow cell C should not be splited.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
 \node[] (A) {
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
      \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{A}}  \\ \hline
      \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{B}}  \\  \hline
      \multirow{4}{*}{C} & D \\ 
       & E \\
       & F \\ 
       & G \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}   
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Current output:


Do you instist on tabular ? tabularray makes all this so easy.

if you're ok with powerfull tabularray

\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
 \node (A) {
 \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {|c|c|},
    row{1-2} = {font=\bfseries},
    hlines,
}
    \SetCell[c=2]{c} A \\
    \SetCell[c=2]{c} B \\
    \SetCell[r=4]{c} C & D \\
      & E \\ 
      & F \\
      & G \\
\end{tblr}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Good answer, can we remove the first cell top/left,right lines?
